# "No matching function for call..." when inheriting

Tags: c++, inheritance, g++, castor

I got a rather strange error, an cannot figure out where the problem is.
First, I had this code :

```
#include <vector>
#include <castor.h>

typedef castor::lref<int> lint;

class LineValid : public castor::relation {
    public:
        LineValid(lint* data, size_t size);
        LineValid(std::vector<lint> data);
        bool operator()() const;

    private:
        void _establishPermutation();
        std::vector<lint> _data;
        castor::relation _permutation;
};
```

In a file livevalid.h, and :

```
#include "linevalid.h"

LineValid::LineValid(lint* data, size_t) : castor::relation {
    /* ... */
}

LineValid::LineValid(std::vector<lint> data) {
    /* ... */
}

/* ... */
```

in linevalid.cpp. My compiler told me "linevalid.cpp:3:45: error: no matching function for call to 'castor::relation::relation()'...", which is true; so I figure out the way castor was working and find a "Coroutine" class. Therefore, I made my class inherit from the Coroutine, giving the following code :

```
class LineValid : public castor::Coroutine //...
```

and

```
LineValid::LineValid(lint* data, size_t size) : castor::Coroutine //...
LineValid::LineValid(std::vector<lint> data) : castor::Coroutine //...
```

And here my compiler told me... exactly the same thing, ie: "linevalid.cpp:3:45: error: no matching function for call to 'castor::relation::relation()...'

Then I thought of removing the inheriting like this :

```
class LineValid {//...
```

and

```
LineValid::LineValid(/*...*/) { //...
```

And my compiler says : "linevalid.cpp:3:45: error: no matching function for call to 'castor::relation::relation()'..."

So here I am, a little confused by this error. Where does it come from ? What further tests can I do to understand what is hapenning ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Have you restarted your development environment, or otherwise reset the compiler? It looks like it's still seeing the original line of code.

Comment: It looks like `castor::relation` doesn't have a default constructor. You need to explicitly initialize all your bases and members of this type in each constructor. Can you show where you are doing this? `_permutation` is only mentioned in your code once.

Comment: n.m. is right. You are looking at what is wrong in the constructor declaration, but the problem is the _permutation data member that needs to be costructed in any case and likely does not have a default constructor.

Comment: _permutation is initialized in "_establishPermutation", which is called in the constructor. I tried removing _permutation from my code, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Nevermind, removing _permutation does actually remove the error... but why cannot I use a function to initialize _permutation if it is called in the constructor ?